# Emacs shell has different behavior from Terminal with GCC

Tags: c++, macos, shell, emacs, terminal

I'm working on a C++ project that requires GCC 4.7 or later. When I call `make` on the command line in Terminal, it works fine, but it fails when I run `M-x compile` in Emacs.

When I run `gcc --version` on the command line, it says

```
gcc (MacPorts gcc47 4.7.3_0+universal) 4.7.3
```

But when I run `gcc --version` from the shell within Emacs, it says

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

I did a little more investigation, and found another difference between Emacs and Terminal. I installed GCC 4.7 using MacPorts on the Terminal; but when I run `port install foo` in Emacs, it says `port: command not found`.

Why does this happen, and how can I get Emacs to use the same version of GCC as Terminal?

Comment: It's the usual macosx problem that your shell's environment is not set in applications started from the dock (e.g. Emacs).

Comment: @Stefan Do you know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

`M-x shell` starts a new shell. For me, it's a bash shell, but it could be csh or zsh or some other shell. When emacs launches a new shell, it runs ~/.emacs_SHELL where SHELL is bash or csh or something. So you can copy your shell startup file to that file and it should hopefully get your path and other environment variables set up correctly.

In my case, I'm a bash user, so I copied by .profile to .emacs_bash and it worked. You might have a .bash_profile or .bashrc instead of a .profile. But the general idea is the same: put emacs shell startup commands in a .bash_WHATEVER file.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you launch gcc in Terminal or via <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>compile</kbd>, the location of gcc executable is determined by `PATH` environment variable (unless it is configured in the Makefile - but if it were the case, you wouldn't have the problem you are describing). So, first of all check it in the Terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

You can double-check the location of the executable using

```
which gcc
```

Then, in emacs,

```
(getenv "PATH")
```

That is what `make` will see when emacs launches it via <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>compile</kbd>. Change the value to what you got in Terminal using `setenv`. You can also change emacs's own variable `exec-path` to be in sync with your `PATH`. That variable is a list of strings (=paths), add paths to it using `add-to-list`.